# Actions on google: conv.device return only coordinates

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to get user location country. My code, basically copied from example, looks like this:

```
    else {
        conv.ask(new Permission({
            context: 'To get your country',
            permissions: ['DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION', 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION'],
        }))
    }

})

app.intent('Get Permission', (conv, params, granted) => {
    // granted: inferred first (and only) argument value, boolean true if granted, false if not
    const explicit = conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION') // also retrievable w/ explicit arguments.get
    const {location} = conv.device;
    console.log('dbgrrr  '+ Object.keys(location));
```

On last line I am trying to figure out what returns in location object, which should be object of type [GoogleActionsV2Location](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/actionssdk_api_v2.googleactionsv2location.html) - but only `coordinates` arrive. How do I get to `regionCode` I need?